# Firebase get push key when user login

Tags: firebase, web, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

Iam trying to get the user push key when he login. I want to use this push key so i can use it to retrieve the user data from other root node.

[image: how to get this key]

Or is it better to just use the uid for the relations?

```
firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(function(user)
{ 


  if(user)
  {

      // get the user push key?
  }


});
```

Comment: Firebase Authentication users don't have any implicitly associated push key. Do you mean their UID? If so, see https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/manage-users#get_the_currently_signed-in_user

Comment: The push key that get auto generated when you insert data with push. I have add a image for you now so you can see what i mean :)

Comment: Please don't store users under a push ID. Instead store them under their UID, which is guaranteed to be the same for a user.

Comment: ahh okay got it :)

Answer (score 0):

Instead on simply pushing in at *Users* database ref, use firebase set with key equal to uid.

Your code will go as:

```
firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(function(user) { 
    if(user){
        var userInfo = /*YOUR USER INFO*/
        firebase.database.ref('users').child(user.uid).set(userInfo);
    }
});
```

*uid* will remain same for a user in a Firebase project. So each time you want to fetch *userInfo* look up at users/${uid} location.